# To disable one-usercontrol with respect to a CheckBoxControl-Checked Property found in another usercontrol in a samewindow through xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Following is my code

```
                <myusrcontrol:settings x:Name="usr1" />

        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Content>

                    <Grid>
                        <myusrcontrol:abcselection  x:Name="usr2"  Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid>

            </TabItem.Content>
        </TabItem>
```

In the above code, I want to disable "usr2" with respect to a CheckBoxControl-Checked Property found  in "usr1" through xaml only,

Kindly let me know if there is any solution,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Slyvain ,it's not duplicate ,here it's different usercontrols

Comment: The problem is exactly the same: you have a custom control `usr2` taht you wish disabled or enabled based on the `CheckBoxControl-Checked` property of your `usr1` control. Change the names of controls and properties, and you have your solution, the key is the binding on ElementName.

Comment: @Slyvain , ok can you tell me how to call the inner element of a usercontrol like "ElementName = usr1.CheckBox1" . I tried this but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The situation is a little bit more complex than in the post I mentioned as duplicate, so here is a working solution:

As far as I know, you need to create a [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (DP) on your UserControl with the Checkbox and bind the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property to this DP.
Then you can bind your `usr2` control on the DP.

Here is the code:

**usr1.xaml**

```c
<UserControl [...]>
   <Grid>
       <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckbox" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:usr1}}, Path=MyCheckboxIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**usr1.xaml.cs (code behind)**

```c
public partial class usr1: UserControl
   {
      public usr1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCheckboxIsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "MyCheckboxIsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(usr1), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

      public bool MyCheckboxIsChecked
      {
         get
         {
            return (bool)GetValue(MyCheckboxIsCheckedProperty);
         }
         set
         {
            SetValue(MyCheckboxIsCheckedProperty, value);
         }
      }
   }
```

**usr2.xaml**

```c
<UserControl [...]>
    <Grid>
         <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```c
<Grid>
      <StackPanel>
         <local:usr1 x:Name="usr1Control" />
         <local:usr2 IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=usr1Control, Path=MyCheckboxIsChecked}" />
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks @slyvain for your help

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark this answer as "Accepted" if it helped you ;)